# Proper way to to structure 32 and 64 bit pre-compiled versions of several dependencies

Tags: linux, build, cross-platform, x86-64

I am working with a team to develop a software package on Linux that has several dependencies (static libraries and binaries used as helper tools). The dependencies are pre-compiled and stored in the following structure:

```
../dependencies/$configuration/include
../dependencies/$configuration/lib
../dependencies/$configuration/bin
...
```

Where, `$configuration` can be "`release`" or "`debug`".

So far, this structure has worked fine for us. But now, we want to support 64-bit version of our software as well. Therefore, I have to store pre-compiled 64-bit version of all the dependencies.

A colleague suggested following structure, used in their project too:

```
../dependencies/$configuration/include/x86
../dependencies/$configuration/include/x64
../dependencies/$configuration/lib/x86
../dependencies/$configuration/lib/x64
...
```

or another suggested:

```
../dependencies/mylib-32
../dependencies/mylib-64
../dependencies/mylib-32-dbg
../dependencies/mylib-64-dbg
```

But I am not sure what is proper solution and have little knowledge in this area. I want to adopt a solution which is easily extendable and well-accepted.

So, my question is: **Is there a best practice for storing different versions of dependencies?**

Also, how should one decide that what is the proper way to go? What could be the important deciding factors?

Comment: I don't think there is a best-practice. The number of folders is the same in both approaches and I've seen both. Headers file can usually be merged but in the end it boils down to whatever it's easier to understand and implement for your team.

Comment: `x64` is Microsoft terminology.  64-bit x86 is called `x86-64` or `amd64` on Linux systems.  32-bit x86 can be called `x86`, but `i386` or `i686` would be more specific.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Okay. I understand. I am working on finding a way to implement the first approach.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for your comment. I appreciate it.

Comment: @MargaretBloom However, can I do the same with binaries too? I that common to do?